# Find the first doc for each property value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the first document that has a specific property.
for example i have 50 docs with property "a":"1", with different dates.
also 100 docs with "a":"2"
is there a way to query the first doc of each "a" value by date?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted, but you could run the following which will show you the results that match a:1 or a:2 and will order the results as you wanted.

```
{
  "sort": {
    "your_timestamp_field": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "a": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "a": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also run multiple queries using `msearch`. For example

**Place the below in a file named requests**

```
{"index": "your-index"}
{"size":1,"sort":{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc"}},"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"term":{"a":"1"}}}}}
{"index": "your-index"}
{"size":1,"sort":{"@timestamp":{"order":"desc"}},"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"term":{"a":"2"}}}}}
```

Then run

`curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/your-index/_msearch --data-binary @requests; echo`

Comment: Quick note: On the second line of `requests` you're missing a closing brace

Comment: thanks i didnt know msearch before. the problem is that i dont have the list of values (guid type) , unless i will bring them before this query.
i was hoping that ES has something built in